# Razor-pages - file is not saving after return FileContentResult

Tags: excel, file, razor-pages

I'm trying to save Excel file on User's desktop, but I have some problem.
Method I call from AJAX:

```
public IActionResult OnPostExportMembersToExcel()
{
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test sheet");
        int currentRow = 1;
        worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "First name";
        (...)
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            currentRow++;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = member.FirstName;
            (...)
        }

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            var content = stream.ToArray();
                    
            return File(content, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Test file.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything pass with no errors, but after return nothing happens. I tried save it with `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` and it worked, but I won't get current user when app will be publish on server.
What should I do to "take" this file after return and let user to download it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a downloaded file to a specific location on the client machine because you do not have access to that for security reasons.  Your code executes on the server. It works on your machine because it is both server and client. The user has to choose what to do with the download.